# What is the right way to use of non-breakable space before math expressions?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I have seen LaTeX code that

1. puts a ~ between *every* math expression and the text preceding it,
2. does not use ~ in this manner at all, and
3. uses a ~ in this way if and only if the math expression is a number (i.e, consists of digits).

I think the first way is not very nice, since it constrains TeX a lot in how it can typeset the rest of the text. I follow the third way, because I vaguely seem to remember reading somewhere that this is how it should be done; but I cannot recollect where, and I don't have any justification for this.

What is the rule to follow here, and what are the typographical/TeX principles behind this rule? It would be great to have references too, to convince obstinate co-authors (if required!).

Similarly, what is the reasoning behind the (almost universally observed) rule that a ~ should precede a \cite{}? Is *this* documented somewhere?

Comment: I would imagine the idea is to put a nbsp before anything that would look out-of-place coming at the beginning of a line. Short (<2 or 3 character) entities usually fall under this category. Obviously it's subjective, though...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The physical effect you would get from a line break at some point is a small pause / distraction in reading, so what I do is use a mental trick: imagine how the sentence sounds with a small pause in the trouble spot(s) when read out loud. Some cases are clearer than others, but in general that works fairly well for me.

Occasionally I see something in the typeset output that looks bad visually even though it sounds OK, then I correct the ties in the input to fix that one break.

As the problem is related to the actual language you are using, you could also ask this question on [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I agree. Don't worry too much about it. Things like *"Chapter~12"* and *"(b)~Show that $f(x)$ is (1)~continuous; (2)~bounded"* are obvious and one should always use ~; however, with the borderline cases, simply have a look at the output. If it looks good, nobody will know if you used ~ "correctly". If it looks bad, tweak it a bit (add ~, hyphenate, rephrase, ...).

Comment: Taco, Jukka,

  Thanks, that gives me a thumb rule to follow.

Answer (score 32):

See chapter~14 of the TeXbook, where Knuth suggests the following ties:

- Chapter~12
- Theorem~1.2
- Appendix~A
- Figure~3
- Table~\hbox{B-8}
- Lemmas 5 and~6
- Donald~E. Knuth
- Luis~I. Trabb~Pardo
- Bartel~Lendert van~der~Waerden
- Charles~XII
- Charles Louis Xavier~Joseph de~la Vall\'ee~Poussin
- dimension~$d$
- width~$w$
- function~$f(x)$
- string~$s$ of length~$l$
- string~$s$ of length $l$~or more
- 1,~2, or~3
- $a$,~$b$, and~$c$.
- 1,~2, \dots,~$n$.
- of~$x$
- from 0 to~1
- increase $z$ by~1
- in common with~$m$
- of $u$~and~$v$.
- equals~$n$
- less than~$\epsilon$
- (given~$X$)
- mod~2
- modulo~$p^e$
- for all large~$n$
- is~15
- is 15~times the height
- (b)~Show that $f(x)$ is (1)~continuous; (2)~bounded

There are even more examples in the exercises, but that covers most cases...

Comment: I must be really dense, I can't seem to figure out any "rules" from these examples; these look quite arbitrary to me. Perhaps I should bite the bullet and read the chapter.

Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I would summarize the rules of these examples as follows:

* Never split an enumerator and its item (e.g.: Chapter~12; (1)~continuous).
* Never let a single number or variable happen at the beginning of a new line or page (e.g.: string~$s$; 1,~2, or~3; Luis~I. Trabb~Pardo).

However, I also don't know a reliable reference on these conventions.

Comment: @gphilip For the record, [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15555/41356) these examples are formulated as rules.