# LaTeX: The Space Between Words

Tags: spacing

I read the book `The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX`, and found this line:

> LaTeX: Tilde '~' generates a space that cannot be enlarged and...

It seems that the tilde make the space smaller when I compare `Mr.~Smith` and `Mr. Smith`.

**Question 1: When shall I generate a space that cannot be enlarged?**

In addition, same in the section `The Space Between Words`, there is a line:

> If a period follows an uppercase letter, this is not taken as a sentence ending,...

However, no matter uppercase or lowercase I follow a period, I cannot find something different.

**Question 2: Can anyone show me an example?**

Thirdly,

> The command \@ in front of a period specifies that this period terminates a sentence even when it follows an uppercase letter.

Similarly, for those two lines, I cannot find any difference.

> I am new to Latex\@. And you?
>
> I am new to Latex. And you?

Comment: The `~` (tilde) is mostly a fixed and *non-breakable* space. -> `Donald~E.~Knuth`

Comment: Have you tried out the examples to be found in `lshort`?

Comment: It depends on (unknown for us) packages that you are using. The behaviour of distance after a dot is controlled by `\frenchspacing`/`\nonfrenchspacing`. Try to use this sitch to see the differences.

Comment: Question 1 a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/when-should-i-use-non-breaking-space. Question 2 a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/is-a-period-after-an-abbreviation-the-same-as-an-end-of-sentence-period.

Comment: you have `xxx ~yyy` which is _two_ spaces a normal ` ` and an additional `~` you just want `xxx~yyy` if you are using `~`.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the second question: The `\@` isn't needed with words ending with lowercase letters. LaTeX assumes then anyway that the period is a end  of sentence marker.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

I am new to LateX\@. And you?

I am new to LateX. And you?

I am new to Latex. And you?

I am new to Latex.\ And you?
\end{document}
```

[image]