# What is the difference between ~\ and \

Tags: syntax

While I was writing one of my first papers in LaTeX, I used the reference/citing style that was used in the example provided by the professor. For referencing or citing, he uses `~\ref{}` or `~\cite{}`, but I noticed that in my document `\ref{}` and `\cite{}` gave the same result. Can anyone explain me difference and notation and when to use which if there is a difference?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This might help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/when-should-i-use-non-breaking-space

Comment: Using `~` will result in a non-breakable whitespace, which means that TeX cannot do a line break there. This is usually what you want with `\cite` or `\ref`, when e.g. having something like `look at Figure~\cite{fig:x}` in your document where you don't want to be the word “Figure” on a different line than the number of the figure.