# Tikzposter: Long list of authors breaking in two lines

Tags: line-breaking, tikzposter, line

I have a problem with a long list of authors. I don't want to beak the name between last name and given name. What I mean is shown for Author "AuthorForThis ABCeAAAAAAAA1" How can I avoid this?

Wishes,
Mike

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait,margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{authblk}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}}
\title{\Huge\textbf{Test Test Titel}}

\author[1]{AuthorForThis ABCa}
\author[1]{AuthorForThis ABCb}
\author[1]{AuthorForThis ABCeAAAAAAAA1}
\author[1]{AuthorForThis ABCd}
\author[2]{AuthorForThis ABCe}
\author[1]{AuthorForThis ABCf}
\affil[1]{Institute 1}
\affil[2]{Institute 2}


\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{\AB@maketitle}
\renewcommand\TP@maketitle{%
   \centering
   \begin{minipage}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        {\bfseries \Huge \sc \@title \par}
        \vspace*{5em}
        {\huge \@author \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \@institute}
    \end{minipage}%
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[scale=0.8,anchor=east,xshift=0.505\linewidth,yshift=3.9cm,inner sep=0pt] {%
       \@titlegraphic
    };
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{Introduction}{
Test jadksfshflishöfhsöofhöoshfs
}

\end{document}
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You could create the titleblock by hand, with all the freedom you need. Unfortunately, this is currently not covered by [How to customize my titlepage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280).

Comment: I think all you want for this is to use a non-breaking space between the two parts of the author name, i.e. `\author[1]{AuthorForThis~ABCeAAAAAAAA1}`

Comment: Yes, this is working. The tilde makes it acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you want for this is to use a non-breaking space between the two parts of the author name, i.e. `\author[1]{AuthorForThis~ABCeAAAAAAAA1}` using `~` rather than  will produce a non-breaking space, preventing a linbreak occuring between the first and second names (see [When should I use non-breaking space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15547/106162) for example for a bit more on the usefulness of the non-breaking spaces).

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait,margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{authblk}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}}
\title{\Huge\textbf{Test Test Titel}}

\author[1]{AuthorForThis~ABCa}
\author[1]{AuthorForThis~ABCb}
\author[1]{AuthorForThis~ABCeAAAAAAAA1}
\author[1]{AuthorForThis~ABCd}
\author[2]{AuthorForThis~ABCe}
\author[1]{AuthorForThis~ABCf}
\affil[1]{Institute 1}
\affil[2]{Institute 2}


\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{\AB@maketitle}
\renewcommand\TP@maketitle{%
   \centering
   \begin{minipage}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        {\bfseries \Huge \sc \@title \par}
        \vspace*{5em}
        {\huge \@author \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \@institute}
    \end{minipage}%
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[scale=0.8,anchor=east,xshift=0.505\linewidth,yshift=3.9cm,inner sep=0pt] {%
       \@titlegraphic
    };
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{Introduction}{
Test jadksfshflishöfhsöofhöoshfs
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Personally i find the codde very very complicated. Titles often need some manual adjusting, especially for a poster, you can do it b hand more easy.

[image: mike1993TikzposterTitle]

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait,margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm]{tikzposter}
\newcommand{\ini}{\textsuperscript{1}}
\newcommand{\inii}{\textsuperscript{2}}
\begin{document}

\block{}{
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\bfseries \Huge The Journey of Walter Wombat \par}
        \vspace*{3em}
        {\huge Carl Capybara\ini, Lazy Lizard\ini, Busy Bee\inii, \par Gabrielle Giraffe\ini, Laura Lion\ini ~and Klaus Koala\inii  \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \ini Institute of Applied Duck Dance\par
        \inii Institute of Experimental Duck Dance\par}
        \hfill\llap{\smash{\includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}}}\par
}

\block{Introduction}{
    This will be a great story.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have 3 additional questions: (1). what does the "*" in "\vspace*{1em}" do? (2). Is it possible to use your suggestions for author and title if I don't use a block as header? (3). How can  I adjust the image in x and y direction?

Comment: @Mike1993 @1) it was in your code, i didn't fiddle with it. @2) not sure what you mean @3) `textpos`, maybe simpler. That would be a new question. :-)

Comment: @Mike1993 The asterisk does one thing: Add space, no matter what.  Without the asterisk: add space, but only, if we aren't at the beginning of a page.

Comment: It's a while I made this. Thanks for explaination regarding to the *.

Comment: To (2): In the real template I haven't a block around authors and title like we see it in the MWE and in your code, Johannes. I didn't use a explicit block in my MWE, but you do. Therfore, I need to know how I can use your code (the author/title part) without a block around it. I thought, it wouldn't work any other way than using this maketitle etc. thingy.

Comment: Perhaps, I wrote a bit cryptic at all. What I want and need to know is the following: How can I use your code (the part with author etc.) without a block around it in head position of the poster?

Comment: Not cryptic at all. But i am a bit busy myself. Post a new question with a link to this one. You will get afew reputation points and probably get a good answer. If you don't within a few days, give me a ping and i will add a bounty ;-)

Comment: I made it and opened a new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354476/tikzposter-and-good-looking-header-many-authors-logo