# TikZposter and good-looking header (many authors + logo)?

Tags: titles, tikzposter

as Johannes told me I should post a new question and set a link to the old more or less answered question: [Tikzposter: Long list of authors breaking in two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353355/tikzposter-long-list-of-authors-breaking-in-two-lines/)

I would like to know how I can use the code snippet from Johannes from above link ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353578/125143)) without a block around it and have the possibility to use a logo and to position it with x-y coordinates?

Here, a MWE:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter} 

\title{Using tikzposter} 
\author{Authors} 
\institute{Test Institute} 

\usetheme{Default}
\usetitlestyle{Empty}
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\block{Creating the document}{The document...} 
\end{document}
```

What I need is a combination of the simplicity of Johannes' code for the "many authors/large title" problem and the possibilities of my own example (x-y coordinates) in the link above for the logo.

Thanks and wishes
Mike

Comment: Out of interest: Why are you using Tikzposter? How did you find it, why did you choose it?

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/LatexPosterExperiments/blob/master/posterTest.png

Comment: The "real" template is a copy of a Powerpoint template I really dislike. I use Tikzposter because of a good documentation and I thought it is "state of the art" in LaTeX community. What is an alternative? I found it by google "scientific poster LaTeX" and there were good-looking examples. :-)

Comment: I don't know what you want to say with the link? But this is what I would like to have what this png shows as header.

Comment: I just added the source code to the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is useful. The authors and institute can be written basically the same way, but use `\\` instead of `\par`. The title needs to be written in a `\parbox` though, because of how `\title` is defined. If you want to avoid that `\parbox`, you'll need to add

```
\makeatletter
% redefine \title macro
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble, *before* `\title`.

To place a logo with coordinates, you can make use of the fact that the whole poster is essentially a big `tikzpicture`, and that the position of the title can be obtained via the macros `\titlepostop`, `\titleposbottom`, `\titleposleft` and `\titleposright`. So you can use normal TikZ features to place the logo exactly where you like it relative to the title, e.g. with

```
\path (\titleposright,\titleposbottom) ++(-1cm,5mm) node[inner sep=0pt,above left] {\includegraphics{example-image}};
```

Place this right after `\maketitle`.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter} 

\newcommand{\ini}{\textsuperscript{1}}
\newcommand{\inii}{\textsuperscript{2}}

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering The Journey of Walter Wombat and Other Wacky Creatures Meaning That the Title Will Span More Than One Line}}
\author{Carl Capybara\ini, Lazy Lizard\ini, Busy Bee\inii,\\
        Gabrielle Giraffe\ini, Laura Lion\ini ~and Klaus Koala\inii} 
\institute{\ini Institute of Applied Duck Dance\\
           \inii Institute of Experimental Duck Dance} 

\usetheme{Default}
\usetitlestyle{Empty}
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\path (\titleposright,\titleposbottom) ++(-1cm,5mm) node[inner sep=0pt,above left] {\includegraphics{example-image}};

\block{Creating the document}{The document...} 
\end{document}
```

Another option might be the example below. You can use Johannes' title code almost directly in `\settitle`, just with the addition of a `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter} 

\newcommand{\ini}{\textsuperscript{1}}
\newcommand{\inii}{\textsuperscript{2}}

\usetheme{Default}
\usetitlestyle{Empty}
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\settitle{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{%
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\bfseries \Huge The Journey of Walter Wombat \par}
        \vspace*{3em}
        {\huge Carl Capybara\ini, Lazy Lizard\ini, Busy Bee\inii, \par Gabrielle Giraffe\ini, Laura Lion\ini ~and Klaus Koala\inii  \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \ini Institute of Applied Duck Dance\par
        \inii Institute of Experimental Duck Dance}
  }
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\path (\titleposright,\titleposbottom) ++(-1cm,5mm) node[inner sep=0pt,above left] {\includegraphics{example-image}};

\block{Creating the document}{The document...} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for adding this answer to this thread. Yes, this is helpful. I always forgot the many possibilities of TikZ. Is there anybody who knows all go them? This es exactly what I wanted.