# Is it necessary to use a non-breaking space when using cleveref?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, typography, cleveref

I came across [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/when-should-i-use-non-breaking-space) question about the instances wherein non-breaking space should be used.

For cross-referencing, I am using [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref). Although its documentation does not indicate anything about non-breaking spaces explicitly, it seems obvious that with cleveref, I no longer need a `tie` preceding the command `\cref{}`. Am I right?

I am asking this because, the linters `chktex` and `lacheck` integrated with my editor had warned me to introduce a tie. Now, after nearly finishing up the thesis (with the non-breaking spaces) and revisiting the question, it seems to me that this is unnecessary. Also, removal of the non-breaking space will lead to a non-negligible difference in pagination.

What is the general consensus on using non-breaking spaces with `cleveref`? It does seem to be unnecessary, and might even have placed unnecessary restrictions on the spacing for the box-glue-penalty model. If I have to remove it, is there a quick `regex` I can run from the command-line?

An obligatory `MWE`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
See~\cref{sec:massenergy} for more details.

\section{Mass-Energy Relationship}\label{sec:massenergy}
According to blah blah ....

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes that seems like a template comment without even reading at what was asked. I am asking a conceptual question whether a need exists to use a non-breaking space preceding the `\cref{}` macro in any old document. If I have used it, will it hurt?

Comment: Not all of use use `cleveref`, and yet some of us can solve issues with packages we don't regularly use.  Without code, you limit your pool of available help to those who already know `cleveref`

Comment: OK. In this case, that is exactly what is needed. A consensus from those who use `cleveref` in their workflow.

Comment: As you wish....

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes   Well, your comment does seem reasonable. So, I have posted a MWE.

Comment: Seeing that `\cref` inserts not just a `1` but a `Section 1`, I would agree that no non-breaking space is needed before it.  While one would not want a linebreak between "Section" and "1", I see no readability issue whatsoever with a linebreak before "Section."

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for your answer. Would you be able to suggest a POSIX- compatible `regex` to strip this out for every instance of `~` preceding `\cref` or `\crefrange`? I have hundreds of such instances in my thesis.

Comment: Can you not just (in your editor) do a global search and replace of "~\cref" with " \cref" (or "\ \cref")?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes   Possibly. I am using `vim`, but it does not have a native project-level search and replace as far as I am aware. I guess this second part of the question is actually out of the scope of this forum. So, I think I shall consider that this question has been fully answered.  If you move your comment to an answer, I shall mark as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of placing a non-breaking space before, let's say, a `\ref` is that you wouldn't want the phrase `Section 1` to be broken across 2 lines.  With `cleveref`, however, the `\cref` provides not just the number, but also the preceding word.  Thus, the need to apply a prior non-breaking space is alleviated.

For example, in the OP's case, Using `See~\cref{...}` prevents a linebreak between "See" and "Section", which not only is not necessary, but as we see in the MWE below, actually prevents proper margination by reducing the number of available breakpoints.

In the 1st line, a non-breaking space is used before the `\cref` and in the 2nd line, it is not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
.\hspace{4.35in minus .1in}See~\cref{sec:massenergy} for more details.

.\hspace{4.35in minus .1in}See \cref{sec:massenergy} for more details.

\section{Mass-Energy Relationship}\label{sec:massenergy}
According to blah blah ....

\end{document}
```

[image]

For a source code that already is coded with such non-breaking spaces, I would recommend using an editor to globally replace instances of `~\cref` with `\ \cref`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, you don’t need to type `~` when using `\cref`.

Note that the tie `~` is needed between label names (such as `section`, `figure`, `theorem`) and label numbers. The tie `~` is not needed between `See` and `section` in your given example.

A quote from the [`cleveref` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) gives us some hint that the package uses `~` automatically:

> **Page 13**: … `\crefrange{thm1}{thm2}` is typeset as
>
> ```
> theorems~\ref{thm1}\crefrangeconjunction\ref{thm2}
> ```