# Usage of LaTeX macro \space (compared with \␣)

Tags: spacing

Occasionally I find that internal package code contains the macro `\space` (defined as `\def\space{ }` by LaTeX). The most-taught way to produce "explicit" spaces in paragraph text is to use `\␣`, and I think I haven't seen any source teach `\space` as a user-level command.

What community knowledge or practices are there regarding the use of `\space`, especially as compared with `\␣`?

---

Here some examples, from the `memoir` class, which uses `\space` as well as `\␣` in its definitions.

- For example it defines `\newcommand*{\booknamenum}{\space}`; this macro is "called between printing the book name and the number".
- A macro the user is more likely to encounter is `\printchapternum`; `memoir` defines it using `\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering\chapnumfont \thechapter\space\space}`, with two consecutive `\space`s.
- The class defines `\wrappingoff` (for use within `verbatim` environments) via `\newcommand*{\wrappingoff}{\def\@xobeysp{\leavevmode\penalty\@M\ }\def\wrapright{}}`.

Related:

- [Exhaustive list of use cases for the interword space \␣](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99543/14996)

---

(An interesting observation regarding visual appearance within code: `a\space\space␣b` and `a\␣\␣b` *within paragraph text* give seemingly the same output (but note that I haven't tested the exact linebreaking behavior). I personally find `\space` visually clearer than `\␣`: when I see the letter string "space", I immediately know what it is. Backslashes and spaces are so ubiquitous in LaTeX that the combination `\␣` is harder to make out on the screen. That said, such aspects should only be considered in contexts where there is functionally no difference between the two: only then can it be considered a question of coding style.)

Comment: `\space` is expandable, `\␣` isn't. Would you please add some examples?

Comment: I think "the combination \␣ is harder to make out on the screen" is a pro here (says the guy who let you replace `\cite{....}` with `[]`).

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz This is a valuable point of view. Let me propose to develop it in the following way: *In a context where `\␣` and `\space` are equivalent with respect to the typographic output, the former (`\␣`) is less obtrusive in user-level (document) code (where textual/mathematical content matters), while the latter (`\space`) is clearer in a programming context (where function/semantics matters).*

Comment: @egreg I've tried adding some example material; feel free to edit as you please.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### `\space`

`\space` expands to the normal space token, a character with code of the space (32, 0x20) and the catcode of 10 (space).

- In opposite of the space token TeX does not collapse several `\space` commands and it is not ignored after command names, when reading the input. Therefore it is often used in error messages, warnings and other messages.
  Example of the LaTeX kernel (`latex.ltx`):

  ```
  \gdef\@badlinearg{%
    \@latex@error{%
      Bad \protect\line\space or \protect\vector
     \space argument}\@ehb}
  ```

### `\␣`

From "The TeXbook" by Donald E. Knuth, "Chapter 25: Summary of Horizontal Mode":

> `\␣`. A control-space command appends glue to the current list, using the same amount that a ⟨space token⟩ inserts when the space factor is 1000.

- As use case it can be used after commands names for typesetting:

  ```
   \TeX\ is a fascinating language.
  ```
- It can not be used in messages, because it is not expandable. The backslash would also appear in the error message above, if `\␣` instead of `\space` had been used there.
- `\␣` sets the normal inter-word space (space factor `1000`), not the prolonged space after sentences. Thus it can also be used after abbreviations. Example:

  ```
  abc.\ is short for abcdef.\@ and
  abcdef.\@ is short for abcdefghi.
  ```

  Here `\␣` is shorter to type (2 characters) than `\@␣` (3 characters). (`\␣` - like `\relax` and many other primitives - is independent from the space factor: it neither uses nor changes it, but ignores it and uses `1000` instead. Note that `\@␣` resets the space factor.) `\space` cannot be used, because it sets the prolonged space according to the space factor settings.

Comment: I thought `\@` after a period ensures that the period is interpreted as an abbreviation period, not a sentence-final period. So `.\␣` and `.\@␣` should work identically I thought.

Comment: Unless one means to denote specifically an abbreviation space where double sentence spacing is used, it seems harmless to use `\space` in place of `\␣` if one has such a preference in one's coding style. (The reverse is of course not true, as you and egreg have explained.) Or are there any caveats to this?

Comment: @LoverofStructure: `\␣` does not change the space factor. With default settings the space factor is `3000` after `a.\␣`, but `1000` after `a.\@ `.

Comment: What is confusing is this: `\␣` inserts a space as if the space factor were `1000`, but you also write that "with default settings the space factor is `3000` after `a.\␣`". Could you help?

Comment: @LoverofStructure: Assuming `\sfcode` of `a` is 1000, `\sfcode` of `.` is 3000, then the space factor is 3000 after the two tokens `a.`. As `\␣` does not change the space factor, it remains 3000 after `a.\␣` as it would after `a.\relax\typeout{...}`.

Answer (score 11):

The main difference between `\space` and `\␣` is that the former obeys the space factor and the latter doesn't. There is another more subtle difference: `\space` expands to a space token, while `\␣` is unexpandable.

The second aspect is relevant in some special situations: suppose you write

```
\spacefactor=3000\space x
```

(in a macro, probably) in order to add a space similar to what follows a sentence ending period; then you'll have a surprise, because *no* space will appear: a space token following a numeric constant is ignored. Only the first space token is ignored, so

```
\spacefactor=3000 \space x
```

would be the correct code.

This means that `\␣` and `\space` are not interchangeable. Ever.

Turning to your examples.

- `\newcommand*{\booknamenum}{\space}` could of course be written `\newcommand*{\booknamenum}{ }`, but the former is clearer. Note, however that `\booknamenum` as defined by `memoir` is not `\ifx` equivalent to `\space`.
- The case of

  ```
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \centering\chapnumfont \thechapter\space\space}
  ```

  is somewhat different and I beg to disagree with how the code is written. If a user redefines `\thechapter` to expand to `\arabic{chapter}.`, then both spaces will be affected by a space factor 3000, which is probably not what's really wanted. The definition should be

  ```
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \centering\chapnumfont \thechapter\ \ }
  ```

  if a double space is desired.
- The redefinition of `\@xobeysp` performed by `\wrappingoff`, namely

  ```
  \def\@xobeysp{\leavevmode\penalty\@M\ }
  ```

  uses `\␣` for the same reason: we don't want a space that's affected by the space factor. The fact that usually in a `verbatim` environment a `\frenchspacing` command is issued shouldn't be taken into account: one might exploit `\@xobeysp` also in other places and this definition uses a predictable space amount.

Comment: Could you proofread the sentence in my question statement with the word "seemingly" and edit accordingly? I'm not sure whether what I wrote there is still true.

Comment: @LoverofStructure They give the same result because `a` doesn't force a space factor larger than 1000. They would give different results if, for instance, a period precedes the double space and `\nonfrenchspacing` is active: with `\space\space` you'd get two extended spaces, with `\␣\␣` only two normal spaces. A line break can be taken only at the left edge of the first space (and the spaces would disappear at the break).

Comment: But that *does* mean that it's permissible for the user to use `\space` instead of `\␣` for reasons of clarity in personal style in *some* cases, no? If you disagree with this for reasons of purity of style (for example out of a desire to keep code free of TeX-/LaTeX-internal macros to the extent possible), that's a sound point of view, but I would think that a user who is familiar with space factor mechanics likely knows what he is doing. That would then make it more an issue of documenting he differences between `\space` and `\␣` for the casual user and steering him to do the right thing.

Comment: The macro `\space` is not documented in the manual and I don't find real uses for it in a document.