# Purpose of "control space"

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I could not find enough information on Google about control space (`\`). What is the purpose of it? Where should it be used?

Comment: Somewhat related question, [spacing - Usage of LaTeX macro \space (compared with \␣) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119717/usage-of-latex-macro-space-compared-with)

Answer (score 12):

The following is taken directly from Knuth's [TeXbook](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook) (**Chapter 3: Controlling TeX**, p 8):

> When a space comes after a control word (an all-letter control
>   sequence), it is ignored by TeX; i.e., it is not considered to be a
>   "real" space belonging to the manuscript that is being typeset. But
>   when a space comes after a control symbol, it's truly a space.
>
> Now the question arises, what do you do if you actually *want* a
>   space to appear after a control word? We will see later that TeX
>   treats two or more consecutive spaces as a single space, so the
>   answer is *not* going to be "type two spaces." The correct
>   answer is to type "control space,"  namely
>
> ```
> \␣
> ```
>
> (the escape character followed by a blank space); TeX will treat
>   this as a space that is not to be ignored. Notice that control-space is a
>   control sequence of the second kind, namely a control symbol, since
>   there is a single nonletter (␣) following the escape character. Two
>   consecutive spaces are considered to be equivalent to a single space,
>   so further spaces immediately following `\␣` will be ignored. But if
>   you want to enter, say, three consecutive spaces into a manuscript you
>   can type `\␣\␣\␣`.  Incidentally, typists are often taught to
>   put two spaces at the ends of sentences; but we will see later that
>   TeX has its own way to produce extra space in such cases. Thus you
>   needn't be consistent in the number of spaces you type.

For example, compare

```
\TeX\ ignores spaces after control words.
```

to

```
\TeX ignores spaces after control words.
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There are not many uses for it besides after control sequences or to ensure non extended spaces after periods that are not punctuation (but in these cases, a tie `~` would be better).

The tie is defined in terms of `\` : in Plain TeX it is

```
\def~{\penalty\@M \ } % tie
```

while in LaTeX we see

```
\def~{\nobreakspace{}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }
```

By the way, there is a difference between the tie in Plain and in LaTeX: if you have a `~` just after an empty line in a Plain TeX document, the penalty would be inserted in vertical mode (not really a big deal, actually).

Knuth likes, sometimes, to add a “very extended” space. This is the end of chapter 15, on page breaking (taken from `texbook.tex`):

```
[...] After the |\output| routine is finished, ^{held-over
insertion} items are placed first on the list of recent contributions, followed
by the vertical list constructed by |\output|, followed by the recent
contributions beginning with the page break. \ (Deep breath.) \ You got that?
```

These are two interword spaces plus the extra space due to the sentence ending period. Such a double space may be employed in headers.

If `\frenchspacing` is in force, then `\`  and `\space` would be equivalent, as `\space` expands to a space token and the space factor wouldn't come into action to make a difference. However, `\`  is possibly clearer than `\space` and they are *not* equivalent under `\nonfrenchspacing`.

In the Knuth example above,

```
break. \space (Deep Breath.)
```

would produce a wider space, because both space tokens would be extended because of the space factor after `.` which is 3000.

---

A tiny quirk: if you have `\`  at the end of a line, the space would be removed and replaced by the `\endlinechar`. Indeed, both Plain and LaTeX define a meaning for `\^^M`

```
\def\^^M{\ } % control <return> = control <space>
```

An input such as

```
\endlinechar=`S
abc\
def\bye%
```

would produce

[image]

If I find myself in need of `\`  at the end of a line, I usually add `%` and, indeed,

```
\endlinechar=`S
abc\ %
def\bye%
```

would produce a space.

Comment: at the end of your first sentence, i'd say "a tie ~ would *usually* be better".  some people insist on not putting commas after "i.e." or "e.g.", and in those cases, a line break is almost always okay.  (i'd prefer the comma, myself, but some authors are adamant, and i prefer to save my energy for dealing with changes in situations where there is real confusion in the original text.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I spoke about *periods* not being punctuation; if I had to avoid a comma after *i.e.*, I'd certainly not want it at the end of a line.

Comment: i've seen some convoluted sentences where "e.g." has been moved to the end of a sentence, such as "that's because aaa and bbb, e.g." (rather than "for example", which i would find preferable).  in that situation, surely you wouldn't want to suppress a line break.  (although you may want to severely chastise the author.)  in that case, the period after "g" performs two functions -- both the abbreviation and the end of the sentence. (i helped keypunch the brown linguistic corpus, which contained some "dual-function" periods; i remember the discussion, but not the resolution.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry, I'm not indulging bad style. `;-)` I consider a two function period worse than letterspacing lowercase.

Comment: Thank you! Concerning “However, `\ ` is possibly clearer than `\space` and they are not equivalent under `\nonfrenchspacing`.”: Which one is stretchable, which one is not? In LaTeX and in text mode and using `\nonfrenchspacing`, is `First sentence. Second sentence.` equivalent to `First sentence.\ Second sentence.` or to `First sentence.\space Second sentence.`?

Comment: @GeekestGeek Both are stretchable, but “backslash-space” isn't influenced by the preceding character being a punctuation sign. To see the difference, why not trying? But it is already explained in the “Deep breath” part, isn't it?

Comment: @egreg Thanks! This means that `First sentence. Second sentence.` is closer to `First sentence.\space Second sentence.` than to `First sentence.\ Second sentence.`, isn't it?

Comment: I also noticed that, say, `some word,\penalty-313\space another word` produces “some word,another word” without a blank after the comma. I guess, `some word,\penalty-313\ another word` would be a better idea to encourage a line break after the comma.

Comment: @GeekestGeek That would be essentially the same, but if a line break is not taken, the version with `\space` will have slightly more space after the comma.