# When should spaces after full stop be escaped?

Tags: spacing, typography

Athough discussion on that question is [still going on](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2544/80088) ([even if third ways exists](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/third_way.png)), it seems that larger spaces after the end of a sentence is preferable in English. By default, LaTeX puts wider spaces after a period (full stop).

I took the habit of escaping spaces (i.e., writing `i.e.\`, or to make it more clear, `i.e.\␣`) after

- Latin locutions, as

  - etc.
  - cf.
- Mathematical expressions, as

  - s.t. (such that)
  - w.r.t. (with respect to)
  - resp. (respectively)

However, according to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1797/34551), which quotes Chapter 14 of the Texbook, and according to any `bbl` file, spaces after names initial should *not* be escaped.
That is, one write

```
Donald~E. Knuth
```

and not

```
Donald~E.\ Knuth
```

I'm confused: shouldn't that space be escaped as well?

Comment: There is no way that a wider space should appear after an abbreviated middle initial.  I can't imagine it being proper in any sense.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes True but the normal advice for bibliographies is based on the fact they (almost) always set `\frenchspacing` so the issue 'goes away'.

Comment: @JosephWright That I can believe.  1) That there should not be a wider gap, but 2) that the space should not be escaped in a bibliography (because the bibliography style takes care of it).

Comment: So, in my acknowledgments, I should write that I am eternally grateful to `D.~E.\ Knuth`, is that correct?

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134840/36686

Comment: Am I missing something (this is from the Not So Short Intro.): *If a period follows an uppercase letter, this is not taken as a sentence ending, since periods after uppercase letters normally occur in abbreviations.*

Comment: @jak123 This does not cover all the cases. For instance, [in French](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1116), if your name is Christophe, then you abbreviate it as `Ch.`, and not as `C.`. But thanks for your remark, which solve partially my problem.

Comment: BTW, you should use cf. not c.f. since it is an abbreviation of a single word "confer". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.

Comment: +1 for citing the cartoon.  the comment by @jak123 covers the situation where the abbreviation is just a single (uppercase) initial.  where a different abbreviation style ("Ch." for "Christophe") is applied, then a "slash-space" should be used; this is probably a good idea even if `\frenchspacing` is used for a bibliography (as it often is), to accommodate such things as author-year citations, which take the string in question out of its original context.

Comment: the proper way is not `etc.\ etc.\ ` but `etc.\@ etc.\@ ` (if I recall correctly)

Comment: @jfbu : only if you use it in macros, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116530/34551 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15017/34551

Comment: @Clément: still, `\@` is the preferable way (as it shows in the source its intent).